# Can't find "Admin account sharing" in admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, testing

I want to setup the Functional Test Framework for Magento 2. based on [Magento Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_quickstart/mtf_quickstart_magento.html#change-security-settings) I should make some changes in Admin here:
[image: Magento Admin] but it seems the field "Admin Account Sharing" has been disappeared from there! here is my Admin screenshot! Does anyone know how should I fix it?
[image: My Admin Page]

Comment: This information is related to developer version (2.1.x), not to 2.0.x.

Comment: What version of Magento do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I checked that both on 2.0.2 and 2.0.7

Comment: For both 2.0.2 and 2.0.7 this option is unavailable

Comment: Could you some one tell me where this entry goes in table for admin Account Sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step to setting that option is removed from the Magento official documentation  and updated.

Reference:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_quickstart/mtf_quickstart_magento.html#change-security-settings